# Which way to grade assignments is better?

Tags: grading

A way is to give specific marks, like 80/100. Another is to give grades like A+, B-. I am not sure which grading scheme is better for the work.

Comment: Which color is better?

Comment: Which country? undergraduate?

Comment: Your college or university probably already has rules for this. Afterall they need to be able to award meaningful GPAs.

Answer (score 4):

If you give one student a 80/100 and another 79/100, is that 1 point difference real or just random noise? In my courses it would be the latter. So, if possible, I tend to avoid such fine grained schemes, that suggest precision which I just cannot deliver. However, I don't have perfect freedom in choosing schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Consult with your university assessment guides as to the standard way they express the grade on student work and follow this to the letter.  Especially for summative tasks, but also for formative tasks.  If a desriptor is available for the grade, then use that also.

This would ensure consistency in assessment feedback.